# What does the if-statement after the for-loop mean?

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

This is one of the programming challenges from Kattis and I already solved it so I wanted to see how others solved it. And so I came across this piece of code but I'm having trouble understanding these two specific lines:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++) if(inTree[i])
```

and

```
for(j=0;i<N;j++) if(inTree[j])
```

I don't get how those if statements work in this algorithm. Is it supposed to check if there is a link between two nodes ? Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 105
int N,T;
float x[MAX], y[MAX];

int inTree[MAX];
int main()
{
  int c,i,j;
  float dx,dy;
  int minp;
  float len,min,weigth;
  scanf("%d",&T);
  while(T--)
  {
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      inTree[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      scanf("%f %f",&x[i],&y[i]);
      /*printf("%d (%f, %f)\n",i+1,x[i],y[i]);*/
    }
    /* Prim's Algorithm */
    c=1;
    inTree[0]=1;
    weigth=0;
    while(c<N)
    {
      min = -1.0;
      for(i=0;i<N;i++) if(inTree[i])
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) if(!inTree[j])
        {
          dx=x[i]-x[j]; dy=y[i]-y[j];
          len=sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
          if(min == -1.0 || len < min)
          {
            min=len;
            minp=j;
          }
        }
      inTree[minp]=1;
      weigth+=min;
      c++;
    }
    printf("%.2f\n",weigth);
    if(T>0)
      printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `if` is executed on each iteration of the loop.  Compare [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3acf302359f1215a).

Comment: Note that this confusion is one of many reasons why it's generally discouraged to omit curly braces for control structures same with combining multiple control structures on a single line. More often than not these things hurt readability if the code and increase the chance for bugs as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` loop statement takes a single statement for the body. Most commonly this statement is a block enclosed in curly braces, i.e.

```
for (...) {
    // multiple statements
}
```

However, any statement can be used instead, including an `if`:

```
for (...)
    if (...) {
        multiple statements
    }
```

Note that there are no curly braces around `if`, because there are no other statements controlled by the `for` loop.

Since whitespace is not significant, the first two lines above can be merged:

```
for (...) if (...) {
    multiple statements
}
```

This is the construct that you have in your program.

Comment: So the curly braces go with the `if` and not the `for-loop`?

Comment: @Acuriousone Correct.